# What function do I need to write to remove from table?

Tags: c#, sql

It's my function to add to a table:

```
public int insertHistory(string title, string description, int isDone, int userId)
{
    int s = -1;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO History(title,description,isDone,userId) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3,@param4)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = title;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 400).Value = description;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.Int).Value = isDone;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param4", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userId;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            s = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

What code do I need to write to remove from the table by title or something?

Comment: You should look up DELETE.

Comment: OT for your own sanity, please name your parameters. It will work the same, but you can easily recognize what each param means - even if you have to fix something in this method next month

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql and the pages next to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked to delete using Title and here is how to do it

```
    public int deleteHistory(string title)
    {
        int s = -1;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "DELETE FROM History WHERE Title = @title)";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = title;
                s = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return s
 }
```

However in this way you could end to delete more records than you want. If two or more records have the same title you will delete all records with the same title. You could mitigate this problem adding also the UserID to the where condition and the relative parameter to the parameters collection.

```
"DELETE FROM History WHERE Title = @title AND UserID = @uid"
```

So you delete only titles of a specific user, but still this is not safe. If your table has an IDENTITY column and you retrieve the values from that column when you read the records then you can pass that unique value to your query and delete specifically only one record.

```
"DELETE FROM History WHERE HistoryID = @hid"
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are using SqlConnection and a plain SQL statement. You need to call a `Delete` statement in your code:

```
public void DeleteHistory(string title)
{

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "delete from History where title= @title";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = title;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```